# Magento Switcher languages not working correctly

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, language

I have changed languages for flags in Magento. But now for example I change language home page `localhost/website/` I click in French flag page goes `localhost/website/fr` make translation now I select product go to `localhost/website/index.php/fr/productname` now here I change language for example Italian it goes to the home page and give me this url `localhost/website/index.php/fr/it`

Do this for all languages

I can not solve this problem if you can help me thank you.

Here is the code `languages.phtml`

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <div class="langs-wrapper">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php if ($_lang->getCode() != 'default'): ?>
        <a class="lang-flag" href="<?php echo $this->getCurrentUrl().$_lang->getCode();?>" style="text-decoration:none;" title="<?php echo $_lang->getCode();?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flags/'.$_lang->getCode().'.gif');?>" alt="<?php echo $_lang->getCode();?>">
        </a>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `href`: `<?php echo $this->getCurrentUrl().$_lang->getCode();?>`

This just takes the current url and appends the language code to it.
Replace that with

```
 <?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl(); ?>
```

Comment: I have one more question if you can answer me why in the home page when pick a language for example: localhost/website/ select French the url now localhost/website/index.php/fr/?___from_store=us I want to remove this "?___from_store=us" just to show "localhost/website/index.php/fr/" for SEO. Thanks again for your help.